# Numerical integration of an unknown function

Tags: math, differential-equations, numerical-integration

For a school project I have to determine a function u(t) of time. I have derived an expression of the following form:

[(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNrYb.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVlz9.png)

with a,b,c,d constants (not necessarily integers). I have figured out that this problem is only solvable with numerical integration with initial condition u(0)=u_0, yet I don't know how to do this particular problem.

I have looked at all the numerical integration methods I have learnt so far, but they all seem to apply for polynomials or for functions where you know the function evaluations at specific points.

Comment: Assuming `b,c > 0`, you can substitute `u(t)=sqrt(c/b)*sinh(v(t))` and reduce the problem to integrating a power of `cosh(v)`. This reduces further to the integration of a rational function, so partial fraction decomposition is involved. This will result in an implicit solution, which can be used to correct a numerical solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways to calculate an approximate value for u(t), some simple but requiring a lot of iterations, and more complex requiring fewer iterations. Assuming a,b,c,d are real numbers, and u_0 = u(0) then for t > 0, one could just split the interval between 0 and t into N sub-intervals and calculate

u_(i+1) = u_i + (du/dt)(t_i)*t/N

where t_i = i*t/N

then,

u_N = u(t).

If N is not sufficiently large, the result will be inaccurate. To obtain a satisfactory N is more art than science. Just printing the results for increasing N should give you an idea of how large N needs to be to obtain the level of accuracy you need. Adding higher order terms (d^2u/dt^2 etc.) can sometimes improve speed and accuracy.

Comment: Do you mean du/dt multiplied by u_i or du_i/dt?

Comment: (du/dt)(u_i) means the derivative du/dt evaluated at u_i.

Comment: Sorry, I made an error. It's (du/dt)(t_i) meaning the derivative du/dt evautated at t_i.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much! My results seem to make sense.

Comment: You're welcome. I don't know why they closed this for not being programming related. Maybe they think you can work out something like this by hand, which you can't. This isn't really integration because there's no summation. It's numerical approximation of a solution to a first order differential equation. Thanks for the tick :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't numerically integrate anything unless you have values for all those constants.

I don't know what numerical integration schemes you looked at, but I think Euler's method or Runga-Kutta would both be worth trying.

You don't say which language you want to use.  Python would be a fine choice.  So would Java.  Lots of libraries to help.

Wolfram Alpha has a closed-form solution [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=u%27%28t%29%20%2Ba*%28b*u%5E2%20%2B%20c%29%5Ed%20%3D%200).  It's a separable, non-linear ODE.  You'll need to know hypergeometric functions to evaluate.